# Pandas index column name issue when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a dataframe from a CSV file where the header with column names includes a name on the index column.

Sample Data
Code i've tried so far:

```
# Open CSV
file= '507_002117.csv'
print(file)
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=6)
df = df.iloc[:, :11]
#print(df.dtypes)
print(df.head(5))

print(df['AlongTrack'])
```

I return something like this:

```
                     Timestamp  AlongTrack  ...     Pitch  Roll
2022-03-31 21:38:30   0.000000    0.000000  ... -0.260261  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:48   0.098491   -0.000042  ... -0.259386  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:53   0.196983   -0.000086  ... -0.249085  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:59   0.295475   -0.000117  ... -0.243554  0.92
2022-03-31 21:55:04   0.393967   -0.000172  ... -0.246343  0.92
```

as you can see the index is properly set as the timestamp, but the column names are all shifted over one.

I've tried using the documentation,
[Pandas Documentation on read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

It looks like index_col would be the ticket, but I can't seem to get it to work setting it at various values, but all it does is shift things over by one row for the index, but the labels are still wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Comment: Hard to know why your CSV isn't getting read properly without actually see the CSV. Include the headers + first 5 rows and the first five columns as text in the question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate this situation by creating a CSV whose column name count is  one less than the number of comma-delimited data columns.  Maybe that is your situation.  Like this:

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO('''Timestamp,AlongTrack,Pitch,Roll
2022-03-31 21:38:30,0.000000, 0.000000,-0.260261,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:48,0.098491,-0.000042,-0.259386,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:53,0.196983,-0.000086,-0.249085,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:59,0.295475,-0.000117,-0.243554,0.92
2022-03-31 21:55:04,0.393967,-0.000172,-0.246343,0.92''')

df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
print(df)

                     Timestamp  AlongTrack     Pitch  Roll
2022-03-31 21:38:30   0.000000    0.000000 -0.260261  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:48   0.098491   -0.000042 -0.259386  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:53   0.196983   -0.000086 -0.249085  0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:59   0.295475   -0.000117 -0.243554  0.92
2022-03-31 21:55:04   0.393967   -0.000172 -0.246343  0.92
```

With the correct number fo column headers we are good-to-go:

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO('''Timestamp,AlongTrack,Pitch,Roll,xtra
2022-03-31 21:38:30,0.000000, 0.000000,-0.260261,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:48,0.098491,-0.000042,-0.259386,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:53,0.196983,-0.000086,-0.249085,0.93
2022-03-31 21:54:59,0.295475,-0.000117,-0.243554,0.92
2022-03-31 21:55:04,0.393967,-0.000172,-0.246343,0.92''')

df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
print(df)

             Timestamp  AlongTrack     Pitch      Roll  xtra
0  2022-03-31 21:38:30    0.000000  0.000000 -0.260261  0.93
1  2022-03-31 21:54:48    0.098491 -0.000042 -0.259386  0.93
2  2022-03-31 21:54:53    0.196983 -0.000086 -0.249085  0.93
3  2022-03-31 21:54:59    0.295475 -0.000117 -0.243554  0.92
4  2022-03-31 21:55:04    0.393967 -0.000172 -0.246343  0.92
```

Looks like the logic is that if the CSV is one column header short then it is assumed that the first column is an unnamed index column.

One way around this would be to manually specify `names=` with your intended column names including the one that is missing.  Then use `skiprows=` to skip over the header to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line of code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0]).reset_index()
df
```

Result:

| index | Timestamp | AlongTrack | Pitch | Roll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | -0.260261 | 0.93 |
| 1 | 0.098491 | -4.2e-05 | -0.259386 | 0.93 |
| 2 | 0.196983 | -8.6e-05 | -0.249085 | 0.93 |
| 3 | 0.295475 | -0.000117 | -0.243554 | 0.92 |
| 4 | 0.393967 | -0.000172 | -0.246343 | 0.92 |

Comment: Stop using your answers for meta commentary; see [answer] and [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, silly problem.
The CSV File had only a carriage return after the header row. adding a column fixes it, or with code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=6, index_col=False)
```

Flagging it false winds up with using a standard index, and then I can just set the index as the timestamp column. Thanks!